# How to import complete folder in any .robot file?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

Problem Statement 
I have a Folder which consist multiple file like few pages object (.py file ) and few module keyword ( .robot file ) . On my testsuite.robot file insatead of calling all .py file as Library and all .robot file as Resource  I want to call complete folder

**App_Name_Folder ( Folder )**
page1.py
*page2.py
page3.py
modularkeyword1.robot 
modularkeyword2.robot*

On my suit file 
*testsuite.robot*
`I want to call App_Name_Folder`

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to create a master resource file with importing all .robot and .py files and then importing the master resource file in your testsuite.robot file as below:

```
# master.robot
*** Settings ***
Resource     App_Name_Folder/modularkeyword1.robot
Resource     App_Name_Folder/modularkeyword2.robot
Library      App_Name_Folder/page1.py
Library      App_Name_Folder/page2.py
Library      App_Name_Folder/page3.py

#testsuite.robot
Resource     master.robot
```

I have given arbitrary paths. Give the actual relative path from your suite file while importing.

Comment: Thanks but can we call the complete App_Name_Folder ? @Sushanta

Comment: I am not aware of any such way to import complete folder..though I will explore more..if found any ..will let you know

Comment: No, you cannot.